# Map tips and the use of relative paths

Tags: qgis, file-path, maptips

I am trying to set up a GIS database in QGIS (2.16.1) containing some geological information. I've created a shapefile (polylines) and added a map-tip to it which displays a cross-section related to the respective line (see image).

[image: example]

[image: HTML in Layer Properties --> Display:]

This works well as long as I use absolute paths in the attribute table of the shapefile, linking to the location of the cross-section.

**BUT** I would like to use relative paths because there is a chance that the folder containing the QGIS file, the shapefiles and the cross-sections will be copied to a different location.

I have tried but did not succeed and google and the search here did not help me. Can someone help me with that?

**One more thing:** Is there a possibility to re-size the map tip according to the size of the images? I know there is a way to set a fixed size but the cross-sections I am displaying have different sizes each time.

I am relatively new to QGIS and Python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In QGIS 2.16.1 you can use the variable @project_folder. This returns the path of the folder the project is saved in. When the data or datafolder is saved in this project folder as well you can concatenate a relative path.

[image]

---

You should ask one question a time, see [the tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour), as this helps other users find the question and answer.

But for the defined width you can add width = "100" in the image tag:

```
<img src= "[%"path"%]" width = "100">
```

See [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp) for other HTML tags as well.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! Both tips worked out. Thank you very much for the helpful and quick reply.

Comment: Happy I could help :)