QGIS 3.28.15: Model designer - Save output to specific choosable folder
I want to enable users to specify a folder where all the output of the model is to be saved when running it in QGIS. The model was created in the model designer. I have searched far and wide and tried different ways to achieve this but none of them work the way I need them to.
The closest I got is this answer (https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/443940).
I added a file/folder input that gets set as a project variable:
Variable name (value): varoutput
Variable value (Model Input): Output Folder

Then I set the output of the tools to "pre-calculated value" and wrote the following to save the output in the folder specified by the user of the model:
@varoutput || '/' || 'Output_1.shp'

When I run the model, it does not create any output at the specified output folder the first time around (and also does not throw any warnings or error). However, when I run it again without restarting QGIS, it will create the output at the path that was specificed in the last instance of the model. I do not understand why this is happening or how I could change it. I tried putting the project variable as a dependency of the tools but it seems to always use the prior Input from the first time the model has been run in the current QGIS instance.
If anyone knows of a proper comprehensive guide to the model designer in QGIS that includes these, in my opinion, relatively basic tasks, then please let me know. I was not able to find anything of use (especially nothing up-to-date).
